# In SQL how do you multiply count()?

Tags: sql

Here is a description of what I am trying to do:
View the property name, "Number of Rooms", "Optimal Daily Value", and "Average Rate" of each active property.(The optimal daily value assumes that all rooms are full and charged at their base rate.)

Here is the srcipt that I came up with but it doesn't work, gives an error:

```
SELECT p.property_name, 'numrooms' AS 'Number of Rooms', 
    'numrooms' * r.base_rate AS 'Optimal Daily Value', 
    AVG(r.base_rate) AS 'Average Rate'   
FROM property p, room r,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT room_id) FROM room AS "numrooms" 
    GROUP BY p.property_name;
```

Comment: `'numrooms'` is a string literal. `numrooms` is an identifier/column alias.

Comment: Please add more info to the "does not work" part. What does it return that you don't want it to return?

Comment: `AS 'Number of Rooms'` is invalid (standard) SQL. Identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes (as you did with `"numrooms"`)

Comment: In SQL Server that `as 'foo'` would be valid but you still can't reference column aliases elsewhere in the same `select` as they are defined.

Comment: This is the error I get when I execute: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 474
Incorrect syntax near ';'.  It's refering to the Group By line and p.property_name is red underlined in SQL server 2008 meaning that something is wrong with that part from what I can tell. The rest of the script has no idication from SQL server that anything is wrong with it. I am very new to SQL, second time using it... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed at some of the column names.

```
SELECT p.property_name, 
COUNT(1) AS [Number of Rooms], 
SUM(r.base_rate) AS [Optimal Daily Value], 
AVG(r.base_rate) AS [Average Rate]   
FROM property p
INNER JOIN room r
ON p.id = r.propertyId
GROUP BY p.property_name
ORDER BY p.property_name
```

The column alias might have to be different depending on your brand of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you provided, I believe something like this might come close to what you are actually looking for, but I'm not sure you can make sense of the data that would be generated by your query:

```
SELECT
    p.property_name
    , numrooms.rooms AS [Number of Rooms]
    , numrooms.rooms * r.base_rate AS [Optimal Daily Value]
    , AVG(r.base_rate) AS [Average Rate]
FROM property p
    , room r
    , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT room_id) AS rooms FROM room GROUP BY p.property_name) numrooms
```

But my recommendation would be to post more details as to what are the primary/foreign keys in the room and property tables so the carthesian joins that are being done by enumerating tables after `FROM` can be replaced with more efficient `JOIN`s.